# How to safely remove, disable, freeze system apps on rooted device?

Tags: root-access, xiaomi, system-apps, miui, disable-app

How to safely remove, disable, freeze system apps on rooted device (Xiaomi Mi9)?

I tried doing it old school on my Mi9 but after removing just absolute bloatware system doesn't boot, had to reinstall stock via fastboot (no biggie but I'd like to avoid that in future ;)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you seen our [bloatware tag wiki](/tags/bloatware/info)?

Comment: There is no safeway with what you are doing unless your OEM provides the source code of the Android your device is running and provided you can make sense out of it. All you can do is to take precautionary measure of making a backup using a custom recovery to fall back to when things go south.

Comment: Or to put it simply: some system apps are safe to remove, but the rest are necessary. GUI apps are usually safe to remove, but non-GUI apps (background services, etc.) are usually not.